# Hive hour() function returns NULL

Tags: function, hadoop, time, hive, difference

Hive's hour function returns NULL. below is my query

select hour(col_name) from hivetable

datatype for col_name is string and value is in format HH:MM:SS

Comment: Please give an example for one value that returns NULL. Also please show the result of hex(col_name) for this value

Comment: Hex value is 30333A30343A3531, while value of col_name is "03:04:51"

Comment: This does not make sense. Please add to the post a reproducible use-case: create table + insert + select.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check the col_name format is correct, either it should have a timestamp format or as 'HH:mm:ss', because using 'hour' function on string time will work. example: hour('HH:mm:ss')

```
hive > select hour('12:58:59') as hour;
OK
hour
12
Time taken: 0.061 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Yes the format is correct the value currently i am using is "03:04:51"

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by using 
select hour(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col_name, 'HH:mm:ss')) from hivetable.

But i am not sure why we need to do this when the input value is string and in correct format which is "HH:mm:ss"